# How to mix mongodb and a traditional db in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongodb, mongomapper

I am considering using MongoDB (mongo-mapper) for a portion of my rails application.  I am not ready to go whole hog MongoDB because there are too many useful gems that depend on a traditional DB.

That being said there are parts of my application that would be great to leverage a document database.

Has anyone had success mixing the two approaches?  How do you link activerecord models with mongomapper models?

Comment: Which gems are you thinking of?  I am currently migrating my app from MySQL to MongoDB.  I was thinking of doing a hybrid approach like yours, but the more I learned about MongoDB the more I realized that I would have huge benefits (in my case) for just migrating everything.  Some of the gems you wish to leave behind might actually not be necessary in the NoSQL world.

Comment: This is what I am using now: acts_as_versioned, formtastic, devise, paperclip, cancan.  I *think* a lot of these will need significant tweaking to get to work with mongo

Comment: Devise and paperclip both work with Mongoid.  Devise used to work with MongoMapper but I think they took it out.

I dunno about cancan, but Mongoid has some basic versioning support: http://mongoid.org/docs/extras

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoMapper doesn't implement ActiveModel yet, but I think there are a few forks on github that do.  You could use Mongoid instead (which does) and your relationships between Mongoid docs and ActiveRecord entries would just magically work.  I know a number of people are doing that.

That said, I wouldn't want to mix them unless I absolutely had to have an RDBMS for some reason.

Comment: It looks like that Mongoid implementing ActiveModel makes it seem that it is the way to go.  I am going to give it a shot this weekend.  I'll report back.  Thanks

Comment: I went with Mongoid, and ported to an all NoSql approach.  Pretty happy with the outcome.

Comment: MongoMapper now implements ActiveModel as of version 0.9, according to the current FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Here a presentation about this issue: http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/541657350/presentation-blending-nosql-and-sql-at-confoo

I don't know ROR so I can't judge it is a good presentation.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at that, and post if it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+Mappers+for+Ruby+and+MongoDB
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center

You need to mixin mongomapper with the model class
This gives you freedom to define the key-value pairs other than activerecord

```
include MongoMapper::Document
```

Dead simple I think.

Comment: But dont the models have to inherit from MongoID? That is not possible now cause those models are inheriting from AR right?